# Appending two XmlObjects

Tags: java, xml, xmlbeans

I have two XmlObjects using XmlBeans. I want to append one XmlObject as an element of the other.

As an example:

XmlObject 1:

```
<Object1>
    <attr><attr/>
    <attr><attr/>
<Object1/>
```

XmlObject 2:

```
<Object2>
    <attr><attr/>
    <attr><attr/>
<Object2/>
```

Appended XmlObject:

```
<Object1>
    <attr><attr/>
    <attr><attr/>
    <Object2>
         <attr><attr/>
         <attr><attr/>
    <Object2/>
<Object1/>
```

I've found a couple links on merging using NodeLists but they don't seem to be quite what I'm looking for. Any help would be great, Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by using DOM Documents. XmlBeans naturally converts to a DOM Document. From there you can use appending methods to add a child node. Once the node is added you can parse the document back to an XmlObject.

Please see below:

```
XmlObject xmlObject = ...;
XmlObject xmlObject1 = ...;

Document myDoc = myXmlObject.getMyXmlObject().getDomNode().getOwnerDocument();
Node newNode = myDoc.importNode(myXmlObject2.getMyXmlObject().getDomNode(), true);
myDoc.getDocumentElement().appendChild(newNode);
XmlObject obj = XmlObject.Factory.parse(myDoc);
```

`obj` being the newly appended document as an XmlObject.